# Event displaying in fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, events, fullcalendar

I want to display event of json from mysql database. But i can't display it in calendar. I think there are some mistakes in events. But i can't point it out.

Here is my code:

calendar.php:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   theme: true,
   draggable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   editable: true,
   /*events: "json_events.php",*/
   events: function(start, end, callback){
    $.getJSON("json_events.php", 
     {
      start: start.getTime(),
      end: end.getTime()
     },
     function(result){
      for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
       var row = result[i];
      }
      //format the result into an array of calevents
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEvent', {id:row[0], title:row[1], start:row[2], end:row[3]} );
      //then pass the calevent array to the callback
      callback(calevents);
     }
    );
   },
   eventClick: function(event){
    editEventShow(event);

   },
   eventDrop: function(event, daydelta, minutedelta) {
    alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + daydelta + ' days\n' + minutedelta + ' minutes\n'+
     '(should probably update your database)');

   },
   dayClick: function(dayDate){
    /*$('#dialog').dialog('open');
    var date, month, year;
    date  = dayDate.getDate();
    month = dayDate.getMonth()+1;
    year = dayDate.getFullYear();
    dayDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + date;*/
    addEventShow(dayDate, this);

   },
   loading: function(bool) {
    if (bool) $('#loading').show();
    else $('#loading').hide();
   },

 });
    });
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>

 body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  }

 #calendar {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

json_events.php:

```
 <?php 
  require("../../../connect/config.php"); 

  $link = mysql_connect("$server","$user","$password") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($db);
  $query = "SELECT id,title,start, end FROM events";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $arr = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr[] = $row; 
  }
  echo json_encode($arr); 
 ?>
```

Can you help me about the problem??

Thanks.

Comment: are you passing start and end to the getJSON function so that you can put a WHERE clause in the SQL query? i don't see it used... is this just for example purposes?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: (new answer)

```
  for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   var row = result[i];
  }
```

the expression in the loop above is going to overwrite `row` in each iteration of the loop. so later when you're calling row[0], row[1], etc, you're not actually getting an array out of it, unless the last result[i] is in fact an array (and if that's the case the loop would be unnecessary)

i can't give you 100% of the answer, but that should get you in the right direction.

update: i looked a little harder and it looks like you need to move the line:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEvent', {id:row[0], title:row[1], start:row[2], end:row[3]} );
```

inside of the for loop.

Comment: Yes and no, there is no error displaying the json_events.php.
But i don't know the right way to format the result in $.getJSON() in events. 

Can you help me for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing JSON that is already in the CalEvent form, you can just provide a URL that returns a JSON string formatted with the information you need - the function to turn it into cal events isn't necessary, as shown in your commented out line.

[JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) will help you figure out if you have correct JSON.  What you're looking for is something along the lines of:

```
[
    {
      id: row[0],
      title: row[1],
      start: row[2],
      end: row[3]
    },
    {
      ... // next event
    },
]
```

as a string returned from json_event.php.